# Getting javascript variables with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to scrap data inside a js script on a distant web page using Python. I woud like to only get the numbers of "**ownerId**" and "**id**". I want to do it on multiple pages so the numbers will be different each time, how can I do that ?

```
var _zf_aab = new zfl_Guestbook('_aab', { ownerId: 12443183, id: 891273218, type: 2 }, _zf_aabb, _zf_aaba, 17, false, '4Yhbn6glH6xXTW3UWh4GceL1mCDcXyiASFBtk_8j-mA=');
```

Thank you

Comment: You get this as a stirng?

Comment: I want to scrap the javascript using Python, sorry it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import re
your_string = "var _zf_aab = new zfl_Guestbook('_aab', { ownerId: 12443183, id: 891273218, type: 2 }, _zf_aabb, _zf_aaba, 17, false, '4Yhbn6glH6xXTW3UWh4GceL1mCDcXyiASFBtk_8j-mA=');"
owner_id = re.search(r'ownerId: ([1-9]+)?,', your_string).group(1)
id = re.search(r'id: ([1-9]+)?,', your_string).group(1)
```